# Explode string after price

Tags: php, explode, preg-split

Say I have a string

```
$what = "1 x Book @ $20 32 x rock music cd @ $400 1 x shipping to india @ $10.5";
```

And I want to explode so that output is

```
Array 
(
    [0] => 1 x Book @ $20
    [1] => 32 x rock music cd @ $400
    [2] => 1 x shipping to india @ $10.50
)
```

I am thinking something like below but dont know which regular expressions to use!

```
 $items = preg_split('/[$????]/', $what);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: preg_split discards the delimiters, so I'd go for another solution, like the proposed by Prasanth Bendra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$str = '1 x Book @ $20 32 x rock music cd @ $400 1 x shipping to india @ $10.5';
preg_match_all('/(?P<match>\d+\s+x\s+[\w\s]+\s+@\s+\$[\d\.]+)/',$str,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match['match']);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 x Book @ $20
    [1] => 32 x rock music cd @ $400
    [2] => 1 x shipping to india @ $10.5
)
```

**Another solution** :

As per Dream Eater' comment : **Smaller way to write it: (.*?\$\d+)\s. – Dream Eater 3 mins ago**

I just added `*` at the end and it works fine.

```
$str = '1 x Book @ $20 32 x rock music cd @ $400 1 x shipping to india @ $10.5';
preg_match_all('/(.*?\$\d+)\s*/',$str,$match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Smaller way to write it: `(.*?\$\d+)\s`.

Comment: This appeared to work on initial testing however now if the value after the dollar sign has a .5 or .6 etc that value disappears from the output array. So as an example 1 x Shipping @ $1.5 becomes.. [KEY] => 1 x Shipping @ $1 .. any ideas?? thanks!

Comment: First solution works fine for me. when I gave input as `$str = '1 x Book @ $20 32 x rock music cd @ $.5 1 x shipping to india @ $10.5';` there is `$.5` in it, I got the output as `Array
(
    [0] => 1 x Book @ $20
    [1] => 32 x rock music cd @ $.5
    [2] => 1 x shipping to india @ $10.5
)`

Comment: Yes first solution works, thanks, still have a problem however as some of the items have a "&" character in the description for example 1 x Book & CD @ $10 when the & character is there the first solution does not work. Second solution works however not for the decimal place so cannot use. Any ideas?? Thank-you so much for your time.

Comment: have figured out a solution - preg_match_all('/(.*\$[\d\.]+)\s*/',$str,$match); - thanks everybody